# How can I get cookie start time in php?

Tags: php, cookies

My problem is cookie has been set with expiry time and in value there is no start or expire time etc but I want to get its start time mean **when this cookie created?**

Basically when user enters into my site and browse through some pages and reach on a specific page where cookie created, now it continuous browsing and reach on some other page where I just want to check is this cookie created within 5 hours or within 1 day etc.

I want this because user may leave site during process completion and come again after some time then I will check if user came in specific time so I want to reopen same page where he left.

**Sorry if my english is not good.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option available to get Cookie Creation `date/time`. Whenever user visits your site, You can simply add a `variable + value([creation_datetime=>2016-06-10 10:10 AM])` in the cookie, and retrieve it whenever you want it.

Here is example

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722084/how-to-read-the-cookie-creation-date-not-expiration?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467326/in-php-how-to-get-time-date-when-cookie-was-set-created?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

You can add current time in cookie value and check anytime when it was created (until it expires)